# Calculate discrete logarithm

Tags: algorithm, math

Given positive integers `b, c, m` where `(b < m) is True` it is to find a positive integer `e` such that

```
(b**e % m == c) is True
```

where ** is exponentiation (e.g. in Ruby, Python or ^ in some other languages) and % is modulo operation. What is the most effective algorithm (with the lowest big-O complexity) to solve it?

Example:

Given b=5; c=8; m=13 this algorithm must find e=7 because 5**7%13 = 8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This isn't a simple problem at all. It is called calculating the [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) and it is the inverse operation to a [modular exponentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

There is no efficient algorithm known. That is, if N denotes the number of bits in m, all known algorithms run in O(2^(N^C)) where C>0.

Comment: Your claim that all known algorithms run in time O(C^N) for some C > 1 is not correct. There is no known algorithm that runs in polynomial time, but there are still known algorithms that are subexponential.

Answer (score 29):

From the % operator I'm assuming that you are working with integers.

You are trying to solve [the Discrete Logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) problem. A reasonable algorithm is [Baby step, giant step](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step), although there are many others, none of which are particularly fast.

The difficulty of finding a fast solution to the discrete logarithm problem is a fundamental part of some popular cryptographic algorithms, so if you find a better solution than any of those on Wikipedia please let me know!

Comment: Hell, if he finds a *really* efficient algorithm he has a fair chance of getting the Field's Medal

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3 Solution:

Thankfully, [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) has [implemented](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.residue_ntheory.discrete_log) this for you!

> SymPy is a Python library for symbolic mathematics. It aims to become a full-featured computer algebra system (CAS) while keeping the code as simple as possible in order to be comprehensible and easily extensible. SymPy is written entirely in Python.

This is the [documentation on the `discrete_log`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html?highlight=discrete#sympy.ntheory.residue_ntheory.discrete_log) function. Use this to import it:

```
from sympy.ntheory import discrete_log
```

Their example computes `\log_7(15) (mod 41)`:

```
>>> discrete_log(41, 15, 7)
3
```

Because of the (state-of-the-art, mind you) algorithms it employs to solve it, you'll get [`O(\sqrt{n})`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) on most inputs you try. It's considerably faster when your prime modulus has the property where `p - 1` factors into a lot of **small** primes.

Consider a prime on the order of 100 bits: (~ 2^{100}). With \sqrt{n} complexity, that's still 2^{50} iterations. That being said, don't reinvent the wheel. This does a pretty good job. I might also add that it was almost 4x times more memory efficient than Mathematica's `MultiplicativeOrder` function when I ran with large-ish inputs (44 MiB vs. 173 MiB).

Answer (score 3):

Since a duplicate of this question was asked under the Python tag, here is a Python implementation of baby step, giant step, which, as @MarkBeyers points out, is a reasonable approach (as long as the modulus isn't too large):

```
def baby_steps_giant_steps(a,b,p,N = None):
    if not N: N = 1 + int(math.sqrt(p))

    #initialize baby_steps table
    baby_steps = {}
    baby_step = 1
    for r in range(N+1):
        baby_steps[baby_step] = r
        baby_step = baby_step * a % p

    #now take the giant steps
    giant_stride = pow(a,(p-2)*N,p)
    giant_step = b
    for q in range(N+1):
        if giant_step in baby_steps:
            return q*N + baby_steps[giant_step]
        else:
            giant_step = giant_step * giant_stride % p
    return "No Match"
```

In the above implementation, an explicit `N` can be passed to fish for a small exponent even if `p` is cryptographically large. It will find the exponent as long as the exponent is smaller than `N**2`. When `N` is omitted, the exponent will always be found, but not necessarily in your lifetime or with your machine's memory if `p` is too large.

For example, if

```
p = 70606432933607
a = 100001
b = 54696545758787
```

then 'pow(a,b,p)' evaluates to 67385023448517

and

```
>>> baby_steps_giant_steps(a,67385023448517,p)
54696545758787
```

This took about 5 seconds on my machine. For the exponent and the modulus of those sizes, I estimate (based on timing experiments) that brute force would have taken several months.

Answer (score 2):

[Discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) is a hard problem

> Computing discrete logarithms is believed to be difficult. No
>   efficient general method for computing discrete logarithms on
>   conventional computers is known.

I will add here a simple bruteforce algorithm which tries every possible value from `1` to `m` and outputs a solution if it was found. Note that there may be more than one solution to the problem or zero solutions at all. This algorithm will return you the smallest possible value or `-1` if it does not exist.

```
def bruteLog(b, c, m):
    s = 1
    for i in xrange(m):
        s = (s * b) % m
        if s == c:
            return i + 1
    return -1

print bruteLog(5, 8, 13)
```

and here you can see that `3` is in fact the solution:

```
print 5**3 % 13
```

There is a better algorithm, but because it is often asked to be implemented in programming competitions, I will just give you a link to [explanation](http://www.infoarena.ro/blog/meet-in-the-middle).

Answer (score 0):

as said the general problem is hard. however a prcatical way to find e if and only if you know e is going to be small (like in your example) would be just to try each e from 1.

btw e==3 is the first solution to your example, and you can obviously find that in 3 steps, compare to solving the non discrete version, and naively looking for integer solutions i.e.

e = log(c + n*m)/log(b) where n is a non-negative integer

which finds e==3 in 9 steps