# Discover pattern in a string of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a personal project in which I want to find out the pattern found in certain [Pisano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) sequence. Each sequence (ex Pisano(3): 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, ...) has a repeating pattern that I want to extract. In this example, the pattern would be (0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1).

So far I've worked on an algorithm that works alright except when the first number of the sequence is found inside the pattern.

```
def hasPattern(seq):
    pBuffer = []
    predict = ''
    i = 0
    check = True
    iSeq = 0
    passThrough = 0
    while (check == True) and passThrough <10:
        val = seq[iSeq]

        if predict == val: #how to resolve the duplicates pattern values? (1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3)
        if iSeq == len(seq)-1:
            check = False                
        if i < len(pBuffer)-1:
            i += 1
        else:
            i = 0
        else:
        i = 0
        iSeq = -1
        passThrough += 1
        pBuffer.append(val)

        predict = pBuffer[i]

        iSeq += 1

        if iSeq == len(seq)-1:
        check = False       

    return {'pattern': pBuffer, 'size': len(pBuffer)}
```

My question is: how should i approach building an algorithm for checking a repetitive pattern in any sequence of numbers (not only Pisano sequences)?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1]

for b in range(2, len(p)/2):
    iterar = True
    for i in range(0,lp-b, b):
        if p[i:i+b]!=p[i+b:i+b+b]:
            iterar = False
            break

    if iterar:
        print "Solution %s: %s" %(b, p[:b])
        break
```

Comment: that's a python 2 only solution. and you could use `else` of `for` loop, which would avoid the `iterar` flag. And last but not least: you should explain your code. Code-only answers are frowned upon.

Answer (score 2):

You can just search for the second occurrance of a 0 followed by a 1 in the sequence:

```
def findPattern(seq):
   for i in range(2, len(seq)-1):
       if seq[i] == 0 and seq[i+1] == 1:
          return {'pattern': seq[:i], 'size': i}
   return {'pattern': [], 'size': -1}  # not found
```

This works for Pisano series because mod(a+b,n) = mod(mod(a,n)+mod(b,n),n), which means that you can compute each number in the Pisano series by adding to two previous numbers together and then finding the modulo n, without having to compute the numbers in the Fibonacci series modulo n. This means that once the original two numbers (0 and 1) repeat then the sequence repeats. Also, for any two numbers in the series there can only be one possible previous number, so you won't get sequences like ABCDEFGEFGEFG etc

Comment: You can shorten this even more because if `s[i] == 0` and `s[i+1] == m`, then `s[k * i] == 0` and `s[k * i + 1] == m ** k` modulo n, so you are looking for the smallest `k` such that `m ** k == 1` mod n.

Comment: What? I don't get it. `[100,100,0,1]` is not a Pisano series.

Comment: @S.Pinkus can you explain your objection ?

Comment: @S.Pinkus The function assumes that `seq` contains a Pisano series and returns the pattern, it's not for checking if it's a Pisano series. If you wanted to check if it's a Pisano series you'd just need to check that the first two elements are 0 and 1 and that s[i]=mod(s[i-2]+s[i-1],n) for each element after that

Comment: "it's not for checking if it's a Pisano series". Oh I see. On closer reading the assumption of a Pisano series is made in the question. Your correct. So your assertion is the sequence (0,1) can never occur in a Pisano series except at the very beginning. What is the proof?

Comment: @S.Pinkus each number in the sequence is a function of the two previous numbers. s[i] = mod(s[i-2]+s[i-1],n), so once 0 and 1 reoccur the sequence will repeat because the formula doesn't depend on anything else. The 0 and 1 will always be preceded by the same number, since s[i-1] = mod(s[i+1]-s[i],n).

Comment: @samgak Ah, got it. Nice.

Comment: @Gribouillis can you please explain how to implement that in Python code?

Comment: @samgak Actually, it turns out that this is a special case of a computationally hard problem: the discrete logarithm problem. There is no known efficient algorithm when n is large (for the general case). User John Coleman posted a python function in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832617/calculate-discrete-logarithm)

Comment: Thank you for answering. In my original question i didn't add that the Pisano sequence is just an example of a sequence that has a repeating pattern. Your answer is refering strictly to Pisano sequences, but I would like to develop a more general algorithm, able to check for repeating patterns on any sequence

Comment: The answer given by JCA gives a general algorithm